# Возможно ли совместить Materializecss и Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Коллеги, не могли бы вы поделиться советом.

В моем проекте мне требуется взять модальные окна из Bootstrap'a, а весь остальной интерфейс построить на Materialize.
Возможно ли такую задумку провернуть?

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, но ты должен понимать, что у них есть общие компоненты, что приведёт к конфликтам. При конфликтах будет использоватся последний подключённый пакет. Но для твоей задачи всё должно работать.

Comment: А можете расписать как сделать правильно? Попытаюсь и очень хочу сделать именно правильно